# Como asignar un valor null dentro de una rutina en MySQL

Tags: mysql

mi pregunta es como puedo hacer en una rutina de MySQL asignar un campo sea **null** por ej:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero hacer lo mismo que se muestra en la linea seleccionada en azul en MySQL, ese codigo pertenece a SQLServer, **como puedo lograr asignar un valor null desde MySQL?.** Tengo la siguiente rutina en MySQL:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería su ayuda. Desde ya gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto te puede funcionar

```
CREATE DEFINER=`test`@`%` PROCEDURE `myProc`(IN myVarParam VARCHAR(40))
BEGIN
  IF myVarParam = '' THEN 
    SET myVarParam = null; 
  END IF;

  ...your code here...
END
```

Comment: **GENIAL!** eso es lo que necesitaba hacer! Gracias por tu respuesta.